# Connecting to different Database based on user MVC EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, mariadb

I have a client that has a different Maria Db database for all its branches. The requirement is that using an azure sql server as the start database to create a MVC web site that allows the user to login. And based on the branch the user is associated to then interact with that branches Maria DB.

How do I connect to a database on the fly as it were? As I can't use dependency injection as I won't know the connection string till after a user has logged in?

Thanks in advance

Matt

I have used dependency injection for the main database that has the user logins etc.

But stumped as how to proceed after that. Happy to create the connection in the Controllers if that works.

Comment: Multi-tenancy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy#multiple-databases-and-connection-strings